# How can I move the arrow without messing up the desired style

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am fixing websites and I am stuck in moving an arrow in woo theme in wordpress.

[image]

What I want is to move the arrow beside(right-side) the "Services" menu item. 
I tried to adjust the padding but it will make the layout size of the menu item smaller and desired output is not met

I tried also to find the background-image of the arrow but it seems nothing is attached image to it.

The site is: `http://67.222.16.144/~chrismol/`

**Q: How can I move the arrow without messing up the desired style?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not find a background image because there isn't any, the arrow is made with CSS's `border` property and the `:after` selector. This code creates the arrow:

```
#navigation .nav li.parent > a:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border: 0.3em solid #ccc;
    border-color: #ccc transparent transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48%;
    right: .8751em;
}
```

To display the arrow right next to the **Services** menu item, you should first of all change the `top:48%` to `top:34%`, next you should add the following CSS rule:

```
#menu-item-1987 a{
    padding-right:32px !important;
}
```

How this answer meets your expectations, if you have any questions let me know. :)

Comment: Finally I got it already. Thanks man for your idea. I didn't know that the arrow is a created using border.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove your `!important` from `#navigation a`

Answer (score 1):

```
#navigation .nav li.parent > a:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border: 0.3em solid #ccc;
    border-color: #ccc transparent transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 36%;
    right: 1px;
}
```